# trying to number 96 qaurters of the day (15 minute interval) in DAX code

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax

I'm working in Power BI and have dates looking like this

```
6-4-2017 12:20:03
```

I want to give each date a number depending on which qauter it is so date stamps with a time between

-00:00:00 and 00:14:59 get number 1

-00:15:00 and 00:29:59 get number 2

-01:15:00 and 01:29:59 gets number 6 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quarter = HOUR(Table[Date])*4+ QUOTIENT(MINUTE(Table[Date]),15) + 1

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! just needed to change your , to ;

Comment: No problem! (deliminators depend on the system locale)